# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have been using Selenium 2.48 with Firefox 38 and was having similar issue in grid. Yesterday I decided to upgrade to 2.52.0 and firefox 44 to see if this issue is somehow related to the version I was using. At least couple of post on SO suggests the compatibility issue which I can confirm is not. I am getting the following on Jenkins

> > org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
> >     oglecode.com","installDate":1455596830287,"updateDate":1455596830287,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":3236332,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"47.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":null},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0} 
> >     1455596837349  addons.xpi  DEBUG  getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com 
> >     1455596837375  addons.xpi  DEBUG  Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"fJru4ZU2iC5a","location":"app-global","version":"44.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1455582992487,"updateDate":1455582992487,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":24166,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"44.0","maxVersion":"44.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[]} 
> >     1455596837375  addons.xpi  DEBUG  getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} 
> >     1455596837383  DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG  Save changes 
> >     1455596837384  addons.xpi  DEBUG  Updating database with changes to installed add-ons 
> >     1455596837385  addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG  Updating add-on states 
> >     1455596837389  addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG  Writing add-ons list 
> >     1455596837430  addons.manager  DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider 
> >     1455596837431  addons.manager  DEBUG  Provider finished startup: XPIProvider 
> >     1455596837432  addons.manager  DEBUG  Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager 
> >     1455596837432  addons.manager  DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager 
> >     1455596837433  addons.manager  DEBUG  Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager 
> >     1455596837436  addons.manager  DEBUG  Starting provider: GMPProvider 
> >     1455596837460  addons.manager  DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider 
> >     1455596837462  addons.manager  DEBUG  Provider finished startup: GMPProvider 
> >     1455596837463  addons.manager  DEBUG  Starting provider: PluginProvider 
> >     1455596837464  addons.manager  DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider 
> >     1455596837465  addons.manager  DEBUG  Provider finished startup: PluginProvider 
> >     1455596837467  addons.manager  DEBUG  Completed startup sequence 
> >     1455596858981  addons.manager  DEBUG  Starting provider: 
> >     1455596858981  addons.manager  DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for 
> >     1455596858983  addons.manager  DEBUG  Provider finished startup: 
> >     1455596873428  DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG  Starting write 
> >     1455596874900  addons.repository  DEBUG  No addons.json found. 
> >     1455596874902  DeferredSave.addons.json  DEBUG  Save changes 
> >     1455596874912  DeferredSave.addons.json  DEBUG  Starting timer 
> >     1455596874962  addons.manager  DEBUG  Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider 
> >     1455596874962  addons.manager  DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider 
> >     1455596874963  addons.manager  DEBUG  Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider 
> >     1455596874970  DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG  Write succeeded 
> >     1455596874971  addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG  XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17 
> >     1455596875013  DeferredSave.addons.json  DEBUG  Starting write

Platform:

1. Windows machines hosting Node and Hub
2. Jenkins on Linux
3. Grid version: 2.52.0 Firefox 44.0

As per [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG) I can confirm this is not compatibility issue

Comment: Have you tried `2.51.0` for shits and giggles? Just to make sure something is not broken in `2.52.0`?

Comment: I have not but I tried using 2.48 and firefox 38

Comment: As per the change log, `2.51.0` was the first version where they tested firefox 44.0